# Powershell Sorting a tuple not working

Tags: sorting, powershell, tuples

This is the most stripped down example of what I am trying and failing to do:

```
@(1, 3, 2) | Select-Object {New-Object "tuple[Int,Int]" $_, 1} | Sort-Object -Property Item1
```

It returns:

```
(2, 1)
(3, 1)
(1, 1)
```

I'm looking to return the list sorted by the first element of the tuple. Obviously in this little demo I could just do the sorting first, but in my actual use case I perform a calculation on the list during the Select-Object phase and then want to sort based on the results of that calculation.

I'm certainly not married to using tuples but I've tried and failed using other options that haven't had any success. I just need to take a list, add additional information to each element of the list based on the result of a calculation and then sort by that additional information.

Feeling really stupid right now given how long this is taking me to figure out so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just adding a custom property to an object, try returning a new object with the additional property. To use your same example with `@(1,3,2)`:

```
@(1, 3, 2) | % {
   [PSCustomObject] @{
      Item1 = $_
      Item2 = 1
   }
} | Sort-Object -Property Item1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort tuples only if you ADD them to a list first.
Sort-order is alway ascending from first item to last item:

```
$list = New-Object 'Collections.ArrayList'
foreach ($x in 1, 3, 2) {$null = $list.add([tuple]::create($x, 1))}
$list.Sort()
$list | select item1, item2
```